# JavaScript Sort DOM

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort DOM based on a `data-*` attribute. The DOM looks like this, albeit repeated and with incrementing ids and different image source:

```html
<div class="col mb-3" data-id="1" data-filter="Owned">
  <div class="card template">
    <img class="card-img w-100 d-block shadow" alt="Default Template" src="abc.jpg">
    <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <a class="btn btn-dark btn-sm template-preview float-end" role="button" target="_blank" href="organization.html/template.html?id=1">Preview</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Default Template</h5>
      <p class="card-text text-success">Owned</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm doing the sorting via a `<select />` element where the `<option />` values is a JSON literal that hold the field and direction, e.g.:

```js
{
  "field": "id",
  "direction": "asc"
}
```

In the `<select />`'s change event, I have the following:

```js
const templateSort_Change = (e) => {
    const templateSort = e.currentTarget;
    const templateSortValue = templateSort.value;
    const sort = JSON.parse(templateSortValue);
    const cols = document.querySelectorAll('div.col');
    const sortedCols = Array.from(cols).sort((a, b) => {
        if (sort.direction === 'desc') {
            return a.dataset[sort.field].toLowerCase() - b.dataset[sort.field].toLowerCase();
        } else {
            return b.dataset[sort.field].toLowerCase() - a.dataset[sort.field].toLowerCase();
        }
    });
    for (let col of cols) {
        col.parentNode.appendChild(col);
    }
}
```

The issue is that when it goes to do the for/of loop, the result of `cols` is the same order every time and looking at the documentation I'm not exactly sure why. I get that I'm doing string comparison, but these ids are still single digits (e.g. 1, 2, 3, etc.).

What am I doing wrong in my `sort` function that is causing the array to return the same order every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues: First, your asc/desc sorting was backward, so I've fixed that. Second, most important, your `for (let col of cols)` loop should iterate over `sortedCols`, not `cols`. Third, I'm not sure how you intended to update the DOM but I've done it by adding a wrapper `<div>` to all your cols.

```js
const templateSort_Change = (e) => {
    const templateSort = e.currentTarget;
    const templateSortValue = templateSort.value;
    const sort = JSON.parse(templateSortValue);
    const cols = document.querySelectorAll('div.col');
    const sortedCols = Array.from(cols).sort((a, b) => {
        if (sort.direction === 'asc') {
            return a.dataset[sort.field].toLowerCase() - b.dataset[sort.field].toLowerCase();
        } else {
            return b.dataset[sort.field].toLowerCase() - a.dataset[sort.field].toLowerCase();
        }
    });
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = '';
    
    for (let col of sortedCols) {
        document.getElementById('container').appendChild(col);
    }
}

document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', templateSort_Change);
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="col mb-3" data-id="1" data-filter="Owned">
      <div class="card template">
        <img class="card-img w-100 d-block shadow" alt="Default Template" src="abc1.jpg">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-sm template-preview float-end" role="button" target="_blank" href="organization.html/template.html?id=1">Preview</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Default Template 1</h5>
          <p class="card-text text-success">Owned 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col mb-3" data-id="2" data-filter="Owned">
      <div class="card template">
        <img class="card-img w-100 d-block shadow" alt="Default Template" src="abc2.jpg">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-sm template-preview float-end" role="button" target="_blank" href="organization.html/template.html?id=1">Preview</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Default Template 2</h5>
          <p class="card-text text-success">Owned 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col mb-3" data-id="3" data-filter="Owned">
      <div class="card template">
        <img class="card-img w-100 d-block shadow" alt="Default Template" src="abc3.jpg">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-sm template-preview float-end" role="button" target="_blank" href="organization.html/template.html?id=1">Preview</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Default Template 3</h5>
          <p class="card-text text-success">Owned 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col mb-3" data-id="4" data-filter="Owned">
      <div class="card template">
        <img class="card-img w-100 d-block shadow" alt="Default Template" src="abc4.jpg">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-sm template-preview float-end" role="button" target="_blank" href="organization.html/template.html?id=1">Preview</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Default Template 4</h5>
          <p class="card-text text-success">Owned 4</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<select>
<option value='{
  "field": "id",
  "direction": "asc"
}'>Asc</option>
<option value='{
  "field": "id",
  "direction": "desc"
}'>Desc</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

For sorting `strings` you need `localeCompare` method, the `minus ( - )` for sorting numbers not string.

```
  const sortedCols = Array.from(cols).sort((a, b) => {
    if (sort.direction === 'desc') {
        return b.dataset[sort.field].localeCompare(a.dataset[sort.field])
    } else {
        return a.dataset[sort.field].localeCompare(b.dataset[sort.field);
    }
});
```

Comment: The strings in OP's case are numeric, e.g. '35' and '4'. Using `localeCompare()` on them will treat them as strings, so `35` will be considered to be *before* `4` (`'35'.localeCompare('4')` == -1). In OP's case, the minus operator will work correctly: if you console.log('35' - '4') you will correctly get 31 because Javascript casts the strings to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

When you do string comparison with `-`, it will return you a `NaN`.

```js
console.log('abc' - 'abd');
console.log('a' - 'b');
```

What you want to do is to use `localeCompare()`.

```js
console.log('abc'.localeCompare('abd'));
console.log('abd'.localeCompare('abc'));
console.log('a'.localeCompare('b'));
console.log('b'.localeCompare('a'));
```

Comment: The strings in OP's case are numeric, e.g. '5' and '2'. If you `console.log('5' - '2')` you will correctly get 3 because Javascript casts the strings to numbers. So while you are technically correct, it doesn't apply to the OP.